# Find whether a given employee name belong to two different Employee Id's?

Tags: prolog

I have Prolog facts in the form of `employee(emp_id, emp_name)` as shown:

```
employee(101,'Jack').
employee(102,'Tom').
employee(103,'Adam').
employee(104,'John').
employee(105,'Jack').
employee(106,'Adam').
employee(107,'Bob').
employee(108,'Pat').
employee(109,'Adam').
employee(110,'Joe').
```

Now, I want to write a clause `'Whether a given employee name belongs to two different employee id ?'` It should return true/false.

I know this seems to be very basic, but as a beginner I am struck with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setof/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3) to get a list of the employee ids any employee has, and succeed only when there are at least 2 ids in that list:

```
multiple_employee(Name):-
  setof(Id, employee(Id, Name), [_,_|_]).  % there are at least 2 ids
```

Sample runs:

```
?- multiple_employee('Jack').
true.

?- multiple_employee('Tom').
false.

?- multiple_employee(X).
X = 'Adam' ;
X = 'Jack' ;
false.
```

Comment: This is a bit hairy because it is not immediately evident what happens if Name is unbound. Yes, Prolog backtracks over the `Name` via `employee(Id, Name)` before collecting all `Id` for (now at least temporarily fixed) `Name`. Still strange.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: Don't see anything strange here. If you go to the provided link, it points to this [doc](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3) which clearly states what happens with free variables not appearing in the template.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
different(X, Y) :-
   employee(IX, X), 
   employee(IY, Y), 
   IX \== IY.

employee(101,'Jack1').
employee(102,'Tom').
employee(103,'Adam1').
employee(104,'John').
employee(105,'Jack2').
employee(106,'Adam2').
employee(107,'Bob').
employee(108,'Pat').
employee(109,'Adam3').
employee(110,'Joe').

?- different('Joe', 'Pat').
true.
?- different('Jack1', 'Jack1').
false.
```

The names must be unique, else it would be impossible to distinguish between say Jack (id 101) and Jack (id 105). Otherwise your model has syntaxic ambiguity and no good can come out of it.

Comment: There is no need for the names to be unique. As in relational databases, only the identifiers (here the employee ids) need to be unique for the relation. The names are derived. There is no problem with having to Jacks.

Answer (score 0):

A modification of peter.cyc's answer:

```
employees_with_same_name(Name,Id1,Id2) :-
   dif(Id1,Id2),        % state that Id1 and Id2 are always "different" (cannot unify, as per "\=")
   employee(Id1,Name),  % grab an employee record, thus fixing Id1 and Name
   employee(Id2,Name).  % grab another employee record with previous Name, fixing Id2
                        % The dif/2 constraint made sure Id1 \= Id2
   

employee(101,'Jack').
employee(102,'Tom').
employee(103,'Adam').
employee(104,'John').
employee(105,'Jack').
employee(106,'Adam').
employee(107,'Bob').
employee(108,'Pat').
employee(109,'Adam').
employee(110,'Joe').
```

Then:

```
?-
employees_with_same_name(N,Id1,Id2).
N = 'Jack',
Id1 = 101,
Id2 = 105 ;
N = 'Adam',
Id1 = 103,
Id2 = 106 ;
N = 'Adam',
Id1 = 103,
Id2 = 109 ;
N = 'Jack',
Id1 = 105,
Id2 = 101 ;
N = 'Adam',
Id1 = 106,
Id2 = 103 ;
N = 'Adam',
Id1 = 106,
Id2 = 109 ;
N = 'Adam',
Id1 = 109,
Id2 = 103 ;
N = 'Adam',
Id1 = 109,
Id2 = 106 ;
false.
```

A variation which collects them all into a single list.

I haven't been able to make this work with a setof-within-setof with caret syntax. Sometimes Prolog is like that. Then it's better to use separate predicates. This version first collects all the names in a separate list of names.

```
employees_with_same_name(Overall) :-      
   setof(Name,SomeId^employee(SomeId,Name),Names),
   setof(
      Name-ForName,   
      (member(Name,Names),
       employees_with_same_name_2(Name,ForName)),
      Overall).
      
employees_with_same_name_2(Name,ForNameSorted) :-
   bagof(IdX,employee(IdX,Name),ForName),  % keep duplicates (there shoudln't be any)
   ForName = [_,_|_],                      % from gusbro's solution: must have at least two ids for that name 
   msort(ForName,ForNameSorted).           % sorting it? why not; use msort/2 to retain duplicates
```

```
?- employees_with_same_name(O).
O = ['Adam'-[103, 106, 109], 'Jack'-[101, 105]].
```

This is of course the SQL statement

```
SELECT E1.Name FROM Employee E1 WHERE EXISTS
   SELECT * FROM Employee E2 WHERE E2.Name = E1.Name AND E2.Id <> E1.Id
```

Comment: Don't you hate it when Stack Overflow has 1970s VT100 80-column code windows when we have screens that are wide enough for a helipad to be built on them?

Comment: There is probably an SQL-to-Predicate transformer out there...

Answer (score 0):

My solution is pretty basic:-

The check predicate checks the name that you are checking. findall finds all the records with that name. If the records are 2 or greater than 2 than it returns true, else false.

```
check(A):-
    findall(A,employee(_,A),LA),
    length(LA,Len),
    Len>=2.

?-check('Jack').
true
?-check('Adam').
true
?-check('Tom').
false
```

If you just want to check that the name is their only twice, then change **Len>=2 to Len=2.**

An update after DuDa's suggestion: check will give me the List of all the names in the List that occur Twice. **Note: I add another record of Joe, so the program should return Jack and Joe.**

**listofduplicates predicate** returns a list with Names that are occurring more than once. **occurrence predicate** takes the **listofduplicates** and **LA** that was generated by **findall**, **occurrence** returns a list with same names packed in a List. (Example: [[Jack,Jack],[Tom]...]. Finally, **nameoccurringtwice predicate** simply uses the packed list and returns us the name which is occurring twice in the list by using length.

```
check(A):-
    findall(P,employee(_,P),LP),
    listofduplicates(LP,LB),
    occurrence(LB,LP,B),
    nameoccurringtwice(B,A),!.

occurrence([],_,[]).
occurrence([H|T],[H2|T2],[V|L]):-
    occurrence2(H,[H2|T2],V),
    occurrence(T,[H2|T2],L).

occurrence2(_,[],[]).
occurrence2(H,[H2|T2],[H|B]):-
    H=H2,
    occurrence2(H,T2,B).
occurrence2(H,[H2|T2],B):-
    H\=H2,
    occurrence2(H,T2,B).

listofduplicates([],[]).
listofduplicates([H|T],L):-
    \+member(H,T),
    listofduplicates(T,L).
listofduplicates([H|T],[H|L]):-
    member(H,T),
    listofduplicates(T,L).

nameoccurringtwice([],[]).
nameoccurringtwice([H|T],[Name|K]):-
    length(H,Len),
    Len=2,
    H=[Name,_],
    nameoccurringtwice(T,K).
nameoccurringtwice([H|T],K):-
    length(H,Len),
    Len\=2,
    nameoccurringtwice(T,K).

?-check(A).
A = ['Jack', 'Joe']
```

Comment: for more exercise: could you rewrite your predicate in a way that it also generates names once? meaning ?-check(P). would produce P='Jack'; P='Adam';false

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind. Do not use the write/prints but alternative answers. so that ?-findall(X,check(X),L). will give the answer L=['Jack', 'Adam']

Comment: @DuDa How about now?

Comment: @DuDa It was not easy. But I am glad I was able to challenge myself. :)

Comment: @DuDa with your code it'll pick those as well which are occurring more than twice, i.e. Adam.

Comment: sorry for deleting my comment, I want to write it as an answer. The question is actually to find a name with two ids, which is open if it is exactly two IDs or at least two IDs. However, the code can be fixed quite easily.

Comment: 'Whether a given employee name belongs to two different employee id ?

Comment: ^^ if you want to have exactly 2 ids: change [ID, _ | _ ] to [ID, _ ]

Comment: @DuDa wow it works :D You should share your answer.

Comment: lol. I didn't post my answer because it has drawbacks. If you ask `?- check('Jack').` you get `true` but if you press `;` for alternative answers it says `false.`. It should just answer `true.` to be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm chipping in too. I initialy had the same idea as Reema: using `findall/3` but I did not like it since it is not a basic predicate. So I challenged myself to write a generator predicate which could generate each Name but only once. This is my result:

```
check(A):- 
    employee(ID,A), 
    findall(TMP,employee(TMP,A),[ID,_|_]).

?- check(A).
A = 'Jack' ;
A = 'Adam' ;
false.

?- findall(A,check(A),B).
B = ['Jack', 'Adam'].

?- check(tom).
false.

?- check('Jack').
true ;
false.
```

I'm not satisfied with the last one but the rest works fine.